# Slimframework + AngularJS routes

Tags: php, angularjs, routes, slim

Well, I'm trying to create a web application with Angular 1.6 and SlimFramework 3.3

The problem is when i try to use the slim framework routes.

I've put all the slim functions inside de "/api" folder.
It works when I try ex: "localhost/api/" but if i try "localhost/api/user" it says "Object not found"

```
// API group
$app->group('/', function () {
// User
  $this->get('/user', 'App\Action\painel\HomeAction:index');
});
```

https://gist.github.com/miorac/28ab8daf84d0c7cedc3101806642c2c6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:
I need to rewrite my .htaccess to that sub-routes. What i did is copy my main htaccess into the /api folder